# e.key is not supported in most browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, addeventlistener, event-listener

In a event listener I am using `e.key`, but it seems it is not supported by many older browsers.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which I can read that `e.keyCode` and `e.which` are deprecated in favor of `e.key`, so I want to use `e.key`, but what should I do when some browsers are not supporting it?

Should I use

```
const key = e.key || String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
```

It just seems that they don't give me the same results if the key is, for instance, a comma.

Comment: Which browsers do you want to support?

Comment: I have just developed in the latest version of Chrome, but now I am on a computer with Chrome 47 instead of 51, and it doesn't support `e.key`

Answer (score 1):

You use whichever is supported by checking them all, starting with the preferred `e.key` which will be supported by all browsers in time

```
if (e.key) {
     var key = e.key;
} else {
    var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
    var key  = String.fromCharCode(code);
}
```

They should return the same character

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
    var key  = String.fromCharCode(code);
    
    console.log(key, e.key)
});
```

```html
<p>Type in the input !</p>
<input id="test">
```

Note that `keyup` and `keydown` events will return different keycodes for certain keys.

Comment: But `e.key` and `e.keyCode` are not the same

Comment: @Jamgreen - For most characters, in most browsers, they will return the same thing. If you want to standarize it and create a map, here's a good overview -> http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: But `e.key` prints the character. The other two prints the code.

Comment: You're right, it does return a string repesentation of some keys. I guess one you could check that somehow? Have to test something

Answer (score 0):

I tried implementing e.key in my application because I read on MDN that e.keyCode and e.which are both depreca`enter code here`ted as well. However, all I see anywhere is still implementations of e.keyCode || e.which, and that exact code still works everywhere and well for me. MDN does not provide any solution or viable implementation for e.key and I see no key codes anywhere either. I say the documentation is wrong. And as stated here, e.key is NOT the same as e.keyCode or e.which. I would like to know what actually is supposed to be replacing e.keyCode or e.which. I am using it for example, in a keydown event. e.key breaks my code. This is the code:

```
[...inputs].forEach(input => input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    console.log(Array.isArray([...inputs]))
    console.log([...inputs])
    const chord = e.keyCode || e.which
    if (chord === 8) {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.currentTarget.value = ''
        heading1.innerHTML = `User Registration Form`;
        heading1.style.color = `#228b22`;
    }
}))
```

And this is the link to the live application:

[User Registration Form Using JS Constraint Validation API](https://interglobalmedia.github.io/js-constraint-api-form-validation/)